# MG-RAST upload through API - curl

Tags: curl, bioinformatics, file-transfer

I want to upload a file to the metagenomics server RAST, but using the following code

```
curl -X POST -H \"auth: AUTHKEY\" -F \"FILE.FASTA\" \"http://api.metagenomics.anl.gov/inbox\"
```

I always get the error

```
Warning: Illegally formatted input field!
curl: option -F: is badly used here
curl: try 'curl --help' or 'curl --manual' for more information
```

Comment: the documentation is here: http://api.metagenomics.anl.gov/api.html#inbox

Comment: Why are you escaping all your quotes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting a syntax error from curl because the `-F` option takes field=value as its argument.  The required field is upload, and the filename needs to be prepended with an "@".

```
curl -X POST -H "auth: AUTHKEY" -F "upload=@FILE.FASTA" "http://api.metagenomics.anl.gov/inbox"
```

will probably do what you intended.